# the meaning of the preposition "from"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

In the sentence "the government has accepted an enforceable undertaking **from** the auditor" I don't understand the meaning of the preposition "from". In this context, I think it should be "to" instead of "from".

Comment: Why do you think it should it be "to"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accept something *from* somebody else, and not *to*.